# Getting ParseObject from User when using Parse.com and C#

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I am having trouble getting a ParseObject that is stored in a User column using the Parse.com service.  Currently I have the User table setup with username, password, and characterData columns. characterData is a ParseObject that has hitPoints and strength as columns.

In my constructor I call:

```
parseUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
characterData = parseUser.Get<ParseObject>("characterData");
Task<ParseObject> fetchTask = characterData.FetchIfNeededAsync();

hitPoints = characterData.Get<float>("hitPoints");
strength = characterData.Get<float>("strength");
```

but when I get to `hitpoint = characterData.Get<float>("hitPoints");` I get the error: `"InvalidOperationException: ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call FetchIfNeededAsync() to get the data."` I've tried using `FetchIfNeededAsync()` but that appears to have no effect. Is there something else that needs to be done, or is there a callback function I need to call?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to check whether FetchIfNeededAsync has finished by using the ContinueWith method. My constructor now looks like:

```
parseUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser;
characterData = parseUser.Get<ParseObject>("characterData");
characterData.FetchIfNeededAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
    hitPoints = characterData.Get<float>("hitPoints");
    strength = characterData.Get<float>("strength");
});
```